# Write Log Information to File in TempDIr of System

Tags: java, yaml, log4j2

I'm trying to write my logs to console and to a file. Using Log4j in my project. Problem is that the file isn't created and no information is written to it.
My `log42.yaml` file looks like this:

```
Configutation:


status: warn



Appenders:
    Console:
      name: CONSOLE
      target: SYSTEM_OUT
      PatternLayout:
         Pattern: "[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"

File:
  - name: APPLICATION
    fileName: ${java.io.tmpdir}/myfile.log
    PatternLayout:
     Pattern: "[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"




Loggers:
      Root:
        level: info
        AppenderRef:
          - ref: CONSOLE
          - ref: APPLICATION
      Logger:
          level: info
          AppenderRef:
            - ref: CONSOLE
        - ref: APPLICATION
```

Console output works. Changing the filepath to other path e.g. on local machine created no file either.

Did I overlooked something?

Comment: do you have permission to write file in the log directory ?

Comment: yes i can write in local tempdir.

Comment: are you using linux by any chance ?

Comment: no testing currently on a windows maschine.

Comment: can you give your directory write permissions for all the users ? this post might help you https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754344(v=ws.11).aspx i am not a windows user , but user which is running java must have write permissions. it seems a permissions issue to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys. 
The problem for not writing or creating a file in temp folder was a bad using of the parameter `${sys:java.io.tmpdir}`.
How you can see it needs the prefix `sys:`

Answer (score 1):

Your YAML file has bath incorrect indentation and the first word in your file is incorrect.

In your file the toplevel structure is a mapping where the `Configutation` (which should be `Configuration`) key has value `null`. Moreover `status`, `Appenders`, `File` and `Loggers` are also keys to the top-level mapping where they should be keys to a mapping that is the value for the key `Configuration`.

You should try something like:

```
Configuration:

  status: warn

  Appenders:
    Console:
      name: CONSOLE
      target: SYSTEM_OUT
      PatternLayout:
         Pattern: "[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"

    File:
      name: APPLICATION
      fileName: ${java.io.tmpdir}/myfile.log
      PatternLayout:
        Pattern: "[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"

  Loggers:
    Root:
      level: info
      AppenderRef:
      - ref: CONSOLE
      - ref: APPLICATION
    Logger:
      level: info
      AppenderRef:
      - ref: CONSOLE
      - ref: APPLICATION
```